# How do I return a specific number of rows (larger than 1), for each of the joined rows from the other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

An SqlFiddle showcasing sample data for my use case is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae57c5d/6

I have a table `category` (`id`, `title`) containing a list of categories, and a table `item`(`id`,`name`,`category_id`) with a foreign key `category_id` that is pointing to a category, and cannot be `NULL`.

If I now wanted to select the latest `item` from each `category`, I could do that by running the following query:

```sql
SELECT item.id, item.name, category.title
FROM category
JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id, category_id 
  FROM item 
  GROUP BY category_id
) AS i_max ON (i_max.category_id = category.id)
JOIN item ON (item.id = i_max.max_id)
ORDER BY item.id DESC
```

That gets me this:

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | name       | title |
+----+------------+-------+
| 15 | Sydney     | City  |
| 10 | Tesla      | Car   |
| 5  | Pear       | Fruit |
+----+------------+-------+
```

But how would I write the query if I wanted 3 latest items from each category?

My expected output in this case would be something like this (order of categories in the output is irrelevant; order of items should be descending when focusing on any given category from the output):

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | name       | title |
+----+------------+-------+
| 15 | Sydney     | City  |
| 14 | London     | City  |
| 13 | Helsinki   | City  |
| 10 | Tesla      | Car   |
| 9  | Ferrari    | Car   |
| 8  | Mitsubishi | Car   |
| 5  | Pear       | Fruit |
| 4  | Watermelon | Fruit |
| 3  | Apple      | Fruit |
+----+------------+-------+
```

Comment: What MySQL version are you using? MySQL 8 and above support window functions.

Comment: I can upgrade to MySQL 8, no problem, if those have significant advantages

Comment: MySQL 8 is a much advanced version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MySQL 8+, you could use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT i.id, i.name, c.title,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.title ORDER BY i.id DESC) rn
    FROM category c
    INNER JOIN item i ON i.category_id = c.id
)

SELECT id, name, title
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY title, id DESC;
```

Comment: Table `i` doesn't exist :) But other than that it works, cheers! (i have to wait until i can accept...)

Answer (score 1):

If you upgrade DB to 8+ as mentioned, you'll be able to use analytic functions such as `DENSE_RANK()`

```
SELECT id, name, title
  FROM
  (    
   SELECT i.id, i.name, c.title,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY i.category_id ORDER BY i.id DESC ) AS dr
     FROM category c
     JOIN item i
       ON i.category_id = c.id
   ) t    
 WHERE dr <= 3  
 ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4a718a5ef8b80ef35f266ab35817e71a)</kbd>

The results with the ties(*the values with the same ranking*) also included in the result set for the case with using `DENSE_RANK()` function, while for `ROW_NUMBER()` it doesn't.

Comment: Ok now i don't know which answer to accept, they both work, and i don't know what the pros and cons are... either way, i appreciate

Comment: you know, i recently discovered on quite a few questions actually, that the accepted solution isn't always the best one (sometimes it's not even on the point), so i'm actually gonna come back tomorrow after i implement both in my real world database, and i'll accept the one that performs better :P